# Master method to embed videos/animations in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

What's the master method to embed Videos/Animations in Powerpoint, such that no Video file is needed to accompany the Powerpoint file in order for the Video to run?

Comment: Generally, with current versions of PPT, just insert the video. The default nowadays is to embed rather than link. It's easy to tell whether it's worked or not:  save the file after adding the video. If the file size grows by the size of the video file you've added, the video is embedded.

Comment: directly inserting/copying pasting generally wouldn't embed the video. it's format dependent. sometimes yes if lucky

Comment: If that's the result  you're seeing, please provide more specifics:  which version of PowerPoint do you use?  What format are your video files?

Comment: my ppt is 2003. i have videos of mp4, avi etc. the only fullproof video that definitely works is .gif

Comment: OK. 2003 would definitely not be what I meant when I referred to "current versions of PPT".  As I recall, 2003 can embed only WAV sound files and no videos at all (other than GIFs ...hadn't thought of that dodge for sneaking in videos in the back door; nice find)

Comment: i also have a 2010 version. but i dont think embedding .mp4 etc is possible. u still need the .mp4 files to put in the same folder

Comment: I'd have to check this to be sure, but IIRC, you might need Quicktime installed in order for 2010 to deal with those. But if you have 2010, try converting the mp4s to .wmv ... 2010 should be able to embed those.

Comment: Guessing you want to use it in a conference talk. You ask for _"What's the __master method__ to embed Videos/Animations in Powerpoint, such that no Video file is needed to accompany the Powerpoint file in order for the Video to run?"_. Interesting. I'm tempted to answer you _"on your laptop !"_.  `:-)`. The problem is that you will present it in a conference in the future, but you are not aware in advance (now) about the software version and even about the OS that will be really used in that conference and time. Even when they write it on the conference site. (Bring anyway a pdf version too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only test using Office 2019, but using the ribbon
*Insert > Movie > Select a movie file from your computer*
does insert the video file into the `.pptx` file itself,
and I have even tested with a video file of 6 GB in size
(which took some time).

The article
[How to embed video in PowerPoint (2007, 2010, 2013, 2016)](https://clipchamp.com/en/blog/2016/embed-video-powerpoint-office)
resumes all the video formats for all versions of PowerPoint:

[image]

Further limitations are
([source](https://www.faasoft.com/articles/mp4-in-powerpoint.html)):

> **PowerPoint 2007 and lower version:** According to Microsoft, PowerPoint 2007 and lower version only support WMV, AVI, ASF, and MPG
>   (MPEG-1) video formats, that's why you can't play MP4 in PowerPoint
>   2007/2003/2002/2000/97/95.
>
> **PowerPoint 2010:** Only support .mp4, .mov, and .qt formats if the Apple QuickTime player is installed.
>
> **PowerPoint 2013:** Only support .mp4 videos encoded with H.264 video (a.k.a. MPEG-4 AVC) and AAC audio. If the source MP4 file doesn't meet
>   the above requirement, PowerPoint won't play it.

Microsoft itself makes these recommendations in
[Video and audio file formats supported in PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/video-and-audio-file-formats-supported-in-powerpoint-d8b12450-26db-4c7b-a5c1-593d3418fb59):

[image]

My conclusion is that video embedding in PowerPoint is chancy enough.
If you are using an older version of PowerPoint, pay attention to the
above requirements. Acceptable videos must be encoded using video and audio
codecs that were common at the time that this Office version was released,
and these codecs will need to be installed (if not already native to Windows).

As there might be a conflict with newer versions of the codecs that are
already installed, this is one reason why in Windows 10 it is better
to use a recent version of Office.

Comment: _"video embedding in PowerPoint is chancy enough"_ you are generous to say the least `:-)`. It was and it can still be a nightmare.